# scala parse wont return correct result

Tags: scala, parsing

I am working on scala and I am trying to make this parser:

```
<expr> ::= <num>
     | (cond (<expr> <expr>) ...) # multi-armed conditional
     | (cond (<expr> <expr>) ... (else <expr>)) # multi-armed conditional w/ else
```

this is my code for this part:

```
  case SList(List(SSym(cond),SList(List(a,b)))) => CondExt(parse(SList(List.apply(a,b))))
```

when I run this code I get this error:

```
Status: CompilationFailure
solution.scala:53: error: type mismatch;
 found   : ExprExt
 required: List[(ExprExt, ExprExt)]
      case SList(List(SSym(cond),SList(List(a,b)))) => CondExt(parse(SList(List.apply(a,b))))
```

How is this error fixed I tried several other different ways:

```
  case SList(List(SSym(cond),SList(List((a,b)),SList(List((c,d)))))) =>  CondExt(SList(List(parse(a),parse(b))))

and for this I get this error:
Status: CompilationFailure
solution.scala:54: error: wrong number of arguments for <none>: (list: List[Library.SExpr])Library.SList
      case SList(List(SSym(cond),SList(List((a,b)),SList(List((c,d)))))) =>  CondExt(SList(List(parse(a),parse(b))))
                                      ^
solution.scala:54: error: not found: value a
      case SList(List(SSym(cond),SList(List((a,b)),SList(List((c,d)))))) =>  CondExt(SList(List(parse(a),parse(b))))
```

How can someone point me to my mistake that I am doing.

Extra Info:

```
case class CondExt(cs: List[(ExprExt, ExprExt)]) extends ExprExt
case class CondEExt(cs: List[(ExprExt, ExprExt)], e: ExprExt) extends ExprExt

sealed abstract class SExpr
case class SNum(n : Int) extends SExpr
case class SSym(s : String) extends SExpr
case class SList(l  : List[SExpr]) extends SExpr


object Parser {
  def parse(str: String): ExprExt = parse(Reader.read(str))

  def parse(sexpr: SExpr): ExprExt = {
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide more code, at least declaration and ancestry of relevant classes (SList, / SSym, CondExt), signature of parse, and if possible the full enclosing method.

Comment: @DidierDupont is this enough info?

Comment: Looks like CondExt is the one asking for List[ExprT, ExprT]. So I guess the problem is with what `parse` returns. What is the signature of `parse`?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
CondExt(parse(SList(List.apply(a,b))))
```

The `parse(SList(...))` calls `parse(arg:SExpr):ExprExt`. This tries to call `CondExt(arg:ExprExt)`, But `CondExt` only has an `apply` method defined for an argument of type `List[(ExprExt, ExprExt)]`.

You either need to make `CondExt` take `ExprExt`s, make `parse` return a `List[(ExprExt, ExprExt)]`, or do something else to make the types match.